# Galaxy Nexus fails to boot after unsuccessful Ubuntu Touch installation

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, galaxy-nexus

I tried to install Ubuntu Touch on my new Galaxy Nexus toro (which I bought today specifically for Ubuntu Touch). I followed the instructions I found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install (installed all the packages, made android backup, unlocked the phone) until I accidentally executed

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b
```

instead of

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b
```

It gave me this output:

```
igor@igor-Inspiron-N5110:~$ phablet-flash cdimage-touch -d grouper -b
INFO:phablet-flash:Device detected as grouper
INFO:phablet-flash:Download directory set to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1
INFO:phablet-flash:Download directory set to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1
INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): cdimage.ubuntu.com
INFO:phablet-flash:Downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
--2013-09-06 21:42:14--  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
Resolving cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.174, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::20, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::21, ...
Connecting to cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7344128 (7,0M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img’

100%[======================================>] 7 344 128   1,73MB/s   in 4,6s   

2013-09-06 21:42:18 (1,53 MB/s) - ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img’ saved [7344128/7344128]

INFO:phablet-flash:Downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
--2013-09-06 21:42:18--  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
Resolving cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.174, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1f, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::20, ...
Connecting to cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 68095300 (65M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img’

100%[======================================>] 68 095 300  2,07MB/s   in 32s    

2013-09-06 21:42:51 (2,02 MB/s) - ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img’ saved [68095300/68095300]

INFO:phablet-flash:Downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
--2013-09-06 21:42:51--  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
Resolving cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.92.174, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::21, 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1f, ...
Connecting to cdimage.ubuntu.com (cdimage.ubuntu.com)|91.189.92.174|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7501824 (7,2M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img’

100%[======================================>] 7 501 824   1,74MB/s   in 4,5s   

2013-09-06 21:42:56 (1,58 MB/s) - ‘/home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img’ saved [7501824/7501824]

INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait
INFO:phablet-flash:Restarting device... wait complete
WARNING:phablet-flash:Device needs to be unlocked for the following to work
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing system to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-system-armel+grouper.img
< waiting for device >
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.044s]
sending 'system' (66499 KB)...
OKAY [  7.697s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [  5.756s]
finished. total time: 13.496s
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing boot to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-boot-armhf+grouper.img
sending 'boot' (7326 KB)...
OKAY [  0.859s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.443s]
finished. total time: 1.302s
INFO:phablet-flash:Flashing recovery to /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
sending 'recovery' (7172 KB)...
OKAY [  0.836s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.458s]
finished. total time: 1.295s
INFO:phablet-flash:Booting /home/igor/Downloads/phablet-flash/ubuntu-touch/20130905.1/saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img
downloading 'boot.img'...
OKAY [  0.828s]
booting...
OKAY [  0.399s]
finished. total time: 1.227s
INFO:phablet-flash:Clearing /data and /cache
error: device not found
ERROR:phablet-flash:Command 'adb shell mount /data' returned
non-zero exit status 255
```

After that, it rebooted the phone, and it the only thing it showed me was a black screen with a picture of a lock and the word "Google" in the middle. The phone did not reacted on pressing any buttons, including the power button. `adb` didn't see the device:

```
~ $ adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 

~ $
```

, which prevented me from restoring android as it described at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install. I tried to reboot it by holding power button, it didn't help. Than I rebooted by unplugging the battery. After that, I tried to boot in recovery mode, but it only showed me aforementioned black screen. `adb` still doesn't see the device.

What can I do now? Where else can I seek for help?

Comment: There is a message that says `WARNING:phablet-flash:Device needs to be unlocked for the following to work` did you unblocked the device as said in the instructions?

Comment: Yes, I believe I did. At least, I followed all the instructions, that should have unlocked it. I did not check the result later, though.

Comment: Can you try to unlock it as the instructions suggest again? If it doesn't work, I think you should go into [live chat](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-touch) and use this information as starting point.

Comment: No luck :-( It is just "waiting for device". `sudo fastboot devices` shows nothing. I'll try that live chat tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### **Revert to factory / Android setup.**

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Look for: 'Restoring Android'

**You will need to put phone into 'Recovery Mode' for this to work.**

---

### **UPDATE** (*further details*)

> **Note:** I have only had to try this for a **Nexus 7** (tablet), as I have several (*2nd hand*) and have nearly *bricked* three of them. I
>   have yet to try with a **Nexus 4** (*don't have one*) or **Nexus 10**
>   (more expensive).

You can usually (with difficulty) still get device into 'Recovery Screen'.

- Power-off (fully powered down) for at least ten seconds.
- Hold 'Power' + 'Volume-Up' (varies between devices/Android version) for only 2-4 seconds.

> ( This may take several attempts. )

- Then you should be able to re-flash, to Google/Android factory.

Comment: His phone is locked, and `adb` don't detect the devices.

Comment: I have had this same issue with a **Nexus 7**. I could (with difficulty) still get to 'Recovery Screen'. *Ten seconds fully powered off; hold power + vol-up (varies between devices) for 2-4 seconds; several attempts; etc.* Then I was able to re-flash to Google/Android *factory*.

Comment: Could you add that as your answer instead. We look into detailed procedures to answer questions.

Comment: I tried your method about ten times, no luck :-( How did you know that you should hold 'Power' + 'Volume-Up'? Maybe the combination is different for Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: ***Sorry.*** The buttons are quite different for: Galaxy Tab 2 7.0, Tab 2 10.1, Nexus 7 (2012), Nexus 10, Galaxy Tab 2 8.0 etc. You need the correct button-combo for the **Galaxy Nexus**. *Some allow Power and both VolUp/VolDwn, others its Power + VolUp, and others Power + VolDwn.*

Comment: 'Power' + "Volume-Down' gave me "ODIN MODE". That's something new. But I still can't see the phone with neither `adb devices` nor `fastboot devices`.

Comment: ODIN is the (inhouse, Windows-based) Samsung firmware loader utility. *I don't know the **Galaxy Nexus**, but that sounds like what you need.*

Comment: All right, I'll try it later when I can put my hands on one of those dirty Windows machines. Thank you!

Comment: There is a Linux version (of Odin), but you might be right. ***Did you try the factory-reset script, with the device in Odin Mode?***

Comment: I'm not sure what is factory-reset script, if it is that `./flash-all.sh` recommended at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install, than yes, I tried.

Comment: It works! Windows machine and [this guide](http://www.androidrootz.com/2012/08/how-to-restore-to-stock-unroot-galaxy.html) did their job. Thank you again, David, your advices really helped! Could you edit your answer so I could accept it, for future generations?